# How to add the value with Gauge.js

Tags: javascript, gauge

I'm actually working with gauge.js. It's working correctly but I would like to add the value just as legend at the bottom of the canvas. In my example I just want to display 41%.
Do you know a way to achieve this part ?

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mopaetxp/

```
<canvas id="foo"></canvas>

var opts = {
lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
angle: 0, // The length of each line
lineWidth: 0.1, // The line thickness
pointer: {
length: 0.9, // The radius of the inner circle
strokeWidth: 0.035, // The rotation offset
color: '#000000' // Fill color
},
limitMax: 'false',   // If true, the pointer will not go past the end of the gauge
colorStart: '#006EAB',   // Colors
colorStop: '#006EAB',    // just experiment with them
strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',   // to see which ones work best for you
generateGradient: true
};
var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // your canvas element
var gauge = new Donut(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
gauge.maxValue = 100; // set max gauge value
gauge.animationSpeed = 10; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
gauge.set(41); // set actual value
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML `LABEL` Tag.check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyumnaswain/mopaetxp/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it's possible to deduct the number by javascript ?

Comment: Just Check http://jsfiddle.net/pradyumnaswain/mopaetxp/2/ . The value of label is set as per gauge value. If you want to deduct the value, u can do that there in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use in HTML:

`<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas-speedometer"></canvas>`
`<span id="gauge-value"></span>`

And in your javascript:

```
gauge.setTextField(document.getElementById('gauge-value'));
```